# Error in the format of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

I have a JSON with this format :

```
[15:17:37,612] ({Rb:"0.6", I:[{id:"cost_reportings_timestamp", label:"cost_reportings_timestamp", type:"date", pattern:""}, {id:"Bureau de M. le Maire min-sum-cost_reportings_cost", label:"Bureau de M. le Maire", type:"number", pattern:""}, {id:"Salle de r\xE9union min-sum-cost_reportings_cost", label:"Salle de r\xE9union", type:"number", pattern:""}, {id:"Secr\xE9tariat / accueil min-sum-cost_reportings_cost", label:"Secr\xE9tariat / accueil", type:"number", pattern:""}], K:[{c:[{v:(new Date(1354921200000))}, {v:0}, {v:1.8221145868301392}, {v:1.0604355335235596}]}, {c:[{v:(new Date(1355007600000))}, {v:0}, {v:2.288118362426758}, {v:0}]}, {c:[{v:(new Date(1355094000000))}, {v:0.4536628723144531}, {v:2.1034255027770996}, {v:1.1031612157821655}]}, {c:[{v:(new Date(1355180400000))}, {v:0.4586494266986847}, {v:2.0204458236694336}, {v:1.9794343709945679}]}, {c:[{v:(new Date(1355266800000))}, {v:0.44572973251342773}, {v:2.406118154525757}, {v:1.0900148153305054}]}, {c:[{v:(new Date(1355353200000))}, {v:1.0 […]
```

I have a problem with this because I used the googlechart and my chart can't read the format of my JSON. The format of my JSON isn't good, it's like this

```
" new Date(2012,11,17) "
```

but I need something like this

```
" Date(2012,11,17) "
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: What is the error ? Did you take a look at the developer console ? Also your JSON seems to be cut at the end of the line.

Comment: the format of my JSON is like this :

Comment: error is this : ( One or more participants failed to draw()

Comment: and i  take a look at the developer console and i have this error in console ([15:34:41,596] Une chaîne vide a été transmise à « getElementById())

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the API, but most likely you need to build the Date object and convert it to a date string before sending the JSON object.

try something like

```
var date1 = new Date(2012,11,17).toJSON();
...
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({...,{"v": date1}...});
```